# Prove that $f$ is bijective.

Tags: analysis, functions

We have that $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and that $|f(x) - f(y)| \geq |x-y|$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. How do I show that $f$ is bijective?

Injective is easy to show because if $f(x) = f(y)$ then $0 \geq |x-y|$ so $x=y$.

How do I show surjective?

Comment: Have you tried using Intermediate Value Theorem? It is continuous after all.

Comment: So the hint given to us is to let $w \in \mathbb{R}$ and $M = |w-f(0)|$. Then we show that $w$ and $f(0)$ are between $f(-M)$ and $f(M)$. I know how that once we prove that, the result follows by IVT. But I'm quite lost on how to prove it's between $f(-M)$ and $f(M)$

Comment: For each $x>y$ we either have $f(x)-f(y)\ge x-y$ or $f(x)-f(y)\le -(x-y)$. You'll probably need to show that it must be the _same_ of these two options for _all_ pairs with $x>y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to exploit the fact, that a continuous function on the real line is bijective if and only if it is strictly monotonous.

Comment: Oh ok this actually helps a lot. I think I now have a good idea on how to approach this question. Thanks!

Comment: $f(x)=e^x$ is strictly increasing but not onto $\Bbb R$.

Comment: $f(x) = e^x$ is indeed a counterexample, so technically my above statement is false. But for your case the following still holds: 

If you can show, that $f(x)$ is strictly monotonous and that $\lim_{x \rightarrow +- \infty} \lvert f(x) \rvert  = \infty$, then bijectivity follows from that (if combined with the fact that $f$ is strictly monotonous).

Comment: The correct affirmative would be injective $\Rightarrow$ monotonous

Comment: If you replace "monotonous" by "strictly monotonous", then the converse is true as well.

Answer (score 4):

Idea:

Injectivity and continuous plus given condition implies  $f(\Bbb R)$ is open. So Try to prove $f(\Bbb R)$ is closed. Finally connectivity of $\Bbb R$ implies $f(\Bbb R)=\Bbb R$